# How to understand two coordinate systems of ARCore

Tags: arcore

How to understand of Camera.getPose() and Frame.getAndroidSensorPose()? Are they using the same row data but different reference coordinate systems? Can they switch to each other？

Are the latencies of the two positions the same?